# Compare text with a file Whether text is listed in the file? [Closed Quest]

Tags: vb.net

i have problem with my Project

my textfeld1 = Emospeak Compare text with a file Whether text is listed in the file.

Sry for my bad English.

This is my load file Function:

```
Public Function INI_ReadValueFromFile(ByVal strSection As String, ByVal strKey As String, ByVal strDefault As String, ByVal strFile As String) As String
     Dim strTemp As String = Space(1024), lLength As Integer
     lLength = GetPrivateProfileString(strSection, strKey, strDefault, strTemp, strTemp.Length, strFile)
     Return (strTemp.Substring(0, lLength))
 End Function
```

My Function can load my .ini file with this text format

"[Hey Elice]

Input=Helles"

but he can not red 2 input.

"[Hey Elice]

Input=Helles

Input=ahiles"

And this is my Code for read my file and textfeld sry again for my bad english.

```
        If Emospeak.Text = INI_ReadValueFromFile("Hey Elice", "Input", " ", ".\Hey Elice.ini") Then
        Emospeak.ResetText()
        EmoPic.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.freudig
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.hey_Jess_rechts, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        index = 45
    End If
```

this code is okay but he read not all text with my file :(
she read only one text line...

Can you help me?

Edit: I found a solution!

```
    Private Sub Emospeak_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Emospeak.TextChanged
    Dim sr1 As New System.IO.FileStream("Hey Elice1.ini", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
    Dim reader1 As New System.IO.StreamReader(sr1)

    Do Until reader1.EndOfStream

        Dim line As String = reader1.ReadLine

        If Emospeak.Text = line Then
            Emospeak.ResetText()
            EmoPic.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.freudig
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.hey_Jess_rechts, AudioPlayMode.Background)
            index = 45
        End If

    Loop
End Sub
```

LG Jess

Closed Quest

Comment: what is `INI_ReadValueFromFile`?

Comment: This is my load file Function:


`Public Function INI_ReadValueFromFile(ByVal strSection As String, ByVal strKey As String, ByVal strDefault As String, ByVal strFile As String) As String
     Dim strTemp As String = Space(1024), lLength As Integer
     lLength = GetPrivateProfileString(strSection, strKey, strDefault, strTemp, strTemp.Length, strFile)
     Return (strTemp.Substring(0, lLength))
 End Function`

ah sry i can not better this but you can now see better this code in my main Question feed

Comment: `GetPrivateProfileString` what does this function do, can you please update post?

Comment: i hope you can now understand this waht i mean
my english is not so good ^^"

Comment: .ini files can't usually have more than one value per name, unless you write code to parse it yoursel. What you could do instead is use a format that does support that feature, such an XML file or maybe JSON.

Comment: I have change now file format to xml or JSON and have load from this 
but same effect

Comment: @zaggler See MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestring

Comment: sure this is the basic coder from my code but idk waht do you mean is this help full for me ?